# Prove that (log n)! = O(n^k)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

i need help to prove this

```
(log n)! = O(n^k)
```

I started with `nlog n <= c*n^k` but could not arrive at the desired solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: let n = 2^u. Then prove that u! is not in O(2^ku) for any k.  Equivalently, prove that u! is not in O(g^u) for any g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n^k = (e^k)^log n` and the factorial grows faster than an exponential (product of growing factors vs. product of constant factors).

Comment: @WillNess: my answer does not require the Stirling approximation.